# HTML overflow in a table

Tags: html

I am working on a very old web page that I cannot access the css or js. I need to put a table inside a table cell with the overflow set to scroll.

I cannot use css or javascript, it has to be HTML inline. The site was built on HTML 3.1.

Before you yell at me for not redesigning, we are, but I have to fix some 508 compliance issues as we begin the project to rebuild the site.

Thanks!

Comment: "The site was built on HTML 3.1" — There is no such thing. HTML 3.0 was never finished then the spec jumped straight to 3.2.

Comment: I stand corrected.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to put a table inside a table cell with the overflow set to scroll.

Control over overflow is only possible with CSS.

You might be able to achieve a similar effect using an iframe and putting the content in an external document … but iframes weren't introduced until HTML 4.

Comment: Time-travel paradox. HTML TABLE - judgement day

Comment: I tried adding a <style> above the content, but the editor built in the page is adding tags that nullify the style. I have tried to use inline styling, but <table style="overflow: scroll" border="1" height="200" width="406" cellpadding="4" > is not producing the scroll bar as I want.